# My newly added user cannot write to folder

Tags: chmod

Suppose I installed ubuntu with the user `usr1` then I added `usr2`. I then create a group `grp1` where this 2 users are added. A folder is owned by `usr1` and has group `grp1`. But when I login as `usr2` I cannot write. The folder has permissions 755...

```
usr2@kmserver:/media/data/www$ groups usr1
usr1 : grp1 ...
usr2@kmserver:/media/data/www$ groups usr2
usr2 : grp1 ...
usr2@kmserver:/media/data$ ls -l
total 20
drwx------ 2 root root 16384 2011-05-12 10:53 lost+found
drwxrwxr-x 2 grp1   grp1    4096 2011-05-12 15:15 www
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: Is the folder 755 or drwxrwxr-x ? Both is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

> "The folder has permissions 755"

Change that to 775.

Comment: ops ... `drwxrwxr-x` is actually 775 alr right